# Using Varnish for only one website on the sever?

Tags: apache, drupal-7, varnish

I am new to varnish, so please bear with me.

I have multiple websites on my server. I don't want varnish to be used for all websites but only for a single website. Varnish has to listen to port 80, right? And apache has to run on another port, right? This means that If I need to access the other websites without them being listened to on varnish, I have to access them through: http://www.nonvarnishsite.com:8080 (or whatever other port number apache is running on?) or can I simply pass the request from varnish to apache and get the output back through varnish without having to specify the port number of the apache port in the http request? Does return(pass) take care of returning the output from apache and will the request remain on port 80?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish and apache should listen on two differents ports if they run on the same machine.

You should see https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleDefault for understand the flow of varnish. The "return(pass)" pass to backend.

A simple example you can see it [here](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/making-sites-fly-with-varnish)